# Robotframework RIDE Mac OS get error

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, robotframework

Mac air 10.9.3 Python: 2.7  wxPython: 2.9  RIDE: 1.2.3

Run "ride.py" will display error.

Here is the error I get: (sorry it is really long) A new window pops up and that has the 
headline "Python has quit unexpectedly" And in the rest of the window it says:

```
Process:         Python [508]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.python
Version:         2.7.5 (2.7.5)
Build Info:      python-76100001000000~1
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [372]
Responsible:     Terminal [368]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib
PlugIn Identifier: libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib
PlugIn Version:    ??? (1)

Date/Time:       2014-05-29 16:29:05.826 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  FB368584-4C8A-9A08-B260-42BC6141A11F


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000d0000024

VM Regions Near 0xd0000024:
    CG shared images       00000000c871f000-00000000c8727000 [   32K] r--/r-- SM=SHM  
--> 
    Submap                 00000000ffff0000-00000000ffff1000 [    4K] r--/r-- SM=PRV  process-only VM submap

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x0090841b wxApp::WakeUpIdle() + 27
1   libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x006bf2f2 wxWakeUpIdle() + 34
2   libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x00875d9e wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent(wxEvent*) + 126
3   libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x008c023c wxWindow::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 284
4   libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x00a8204c wxPanelBase::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 60
5   _windows_.so                    0x01d31f41 _wrap_new_Panel + 1121
6   org.python.python               0x0008426a PyCFunction_Call + 78
7   org.python.python               0x000cfdfe PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15833
8   org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
9   org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
10  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
11  org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
12  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
13  org.python.python               0x000cfc0d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15336
14  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
15  org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
16  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
17  org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
18  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
19  org.python.python               0x000cfc0d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15336
20  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
21  org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
22  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
23  org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
24  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
25  org.python.python               0x000cff08 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16099
26  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
27  org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
28  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
29  org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
30  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
31  org.python.python               0x0009b2e7 0x4c000 + 324327
32  org.python.python               0x00097260 0x4c000 + 307808
33  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
34  org.python.python               0x000cfc0d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15336
35  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
36  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
37  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
38  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
39  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
40  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
41  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
42  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
43  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
44  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
45  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
46  org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
47  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
48  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
49  org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
50  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
51  org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
52  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
53  org.python.python               0x0005f3d1 0x4c000 + 78801
54  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
55  org.python.python               0x000cfc0d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15336
56  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
57  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
58  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
59  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
60  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
61  org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
62  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
63  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
64  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
65  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
66  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
67  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
68  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
69  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
70  org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
71  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
72  org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
73  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
74  org.python.python               0x000d1379 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 94
75  _core_.so                       0x0047cc7e wxPyCallback::EventThunker(wxEvent&) + 334
76  libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x00726f2f wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const + 95
77  libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x00872c98 wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&) + 104
78  libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x00874008 wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable(wxEvent&) + 88
79  libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x008750fd wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&) + 45
80  libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x0087516c wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&) + 60
81  libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x008751e1 wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&) + 81
82  libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib    0x00b3594e wxScrollHelperEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&) + 46
83  _core_.so                       0x004d1219 _wrap_EvtHandler_ProcessEvent + 265
84  org.python.python               0x0008426a PyCFunction_Call + 78
85  org.python.python               0x000cfdfe PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15833
86  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
87  org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
88  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
89  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
90  org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
91  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
92  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
93  org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
94  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
95  org.python.python               0x000cff08 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16099
96  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
97  org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
98  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
99  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
100 org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
101 org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
102 org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
103 org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
104 org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
105 org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
106 org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
107 org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
108 org.python.python               0x000d1379 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 94
109 _core_.so                       0x00474369 wxPyApp::_BootstrapApp() + 793
110 _core_.so                       0x004bd8ee _wrap_PyApp__BootstrapApp + 94
111 org.python.python               0x0008426a PyCFunction_Call + 78
112 org.python.python               0x000cfdfe PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15833
113 org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
114 org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
115 org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
116 org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
117 org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
118 org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
119 org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
120 org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
121 org.python.python               0x000cfc0d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15336
122 org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
123 org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
124 org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
125 org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
126 org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
127 org.python.python               0x0009b2e7 0x4c000 + 324327
128 org.python.python               0x00097260 0x4c000 + 307808
129 org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
130 org.python.python               0x000cfc0d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15336
131 org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
132 org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
133 org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
134 org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
135 org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
136 org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
137 org.python.python               0x000cff08 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16099
138 org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
139 org.python.python               0x000cb90e PyEval_EvalCode + 87
140 org.python.python               0x000e8d91 0x4c000 + 642449
141 org.python.python               0x000e8e33 PyRun_FileExFlags + 138
142 org.python.python               0x000e8988 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 710
143 org.python.python               0x000e856c PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 106
144 org.python.python               0x000fa5a8 Py_Main + 3440
145 libdyld.dylib                   0x96228701 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94754992 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x94d99899 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 238
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x94d99532 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94754046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d8dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dccce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94754046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d8dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dccce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94754046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d8dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dccce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x947537ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d9d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dbbd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   org.python.python               0x000f845b PyThread_acquire_lock + 120
4   org.python.python               0x000fbd05 0x4c000 + 720133
5   org.python.python               0x0008426a PyCFunction_Call + 78
6   org.python.python               0x000ce0f7 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8402
7   org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
8   org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
9   org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
10  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
11  org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
12  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
13  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
14  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
15  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
16  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
17  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
18  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
19  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
20  org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
21  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
22  org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
23  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
24  org.python.python               0x000d1379 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 94
25  org.python.python               0x000fc1c7 0x4c000 + 721351
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d75fb _pthread_body + 144
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d7485 _pthread_start + 130
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dccf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94753ace __select + 10
1   select.so                       0x02931383 0x292f000 + 9091
2   org.python.python               0x0008426a PyCFunction_Call + 78
3   org.python.python               0x000cfdfe PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15833
4   org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
5   org.python.python               0x000d1c57 0x4c000 + 547927
6   org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
7   org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
8   org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
9   org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
10  org.python.python               0x000cff08 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16099
11  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
12  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
13  org.python.python               0x000d1be9 0x4c000 + 547817
14  org.python.python               0x000cf461 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13372
15  org.python.python               0x000cbecf PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1468
16  org.python.python               0x00073e7c 0x4c000 + 163452
17  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
18  org.python.python               0x000600b6 0x4c000 + 82102
19  org.python.python               0x000559c9 PyObject_Call + 99
20  org.python.python               0x000d1379 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 94
21  org.python.python               0x000fc1c7 0x4c000 + 721351
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d75fb _pthread_body + 144
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d7485 _pthread_start + 130
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dccf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94754046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d8dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dccce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 8:: com.apple.appkit-heartbeat
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94753b76 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9633dfb7 nanosleep$UNIX2003 + 219
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9633de62 usleep$UNIX2003 + 60
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x98e51a4c -[NSUIHeartBeat _heartBeatThread:] + 2318
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x93238f0e -[NSThread main] + 45
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x93238e66 __NSThread__main__ + 1426
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d75fb _pthread_body + 144
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d7485 _pthread_start + 130
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dccf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94754046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982d8dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x982dccce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0xd0000000  ebx: 0x00908409  ecx: 0xbffb5bc0  edx: 0x7964f580
  edi: 0x7aebe690  esi: 0x7aec2610  ebp: 0xbffb5cb8  esp: 0xbffb5cb4
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x0090841b   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0xd0000024

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: Consider adding more information and question.

Answer (score 0):

Ride has issues on Mac. This is regularly mentioned in the [Robot Framework Mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/robotframework-users). And [there is an open issue to support wxPython 2.9](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-ride/issues/detail?id=888) (the one you have) with Ride. I chose to gave up Ride and work with [TextMate](https://api.textmate.org/downloads/beta) with the [appropriate bundle](https://bitbucket.org/jussimalinen/robot.tmbundle/wiki/Home). Works fine for me.